# Title in node--article twig template

Tags: theming, 8, entities

In `node--article.html.twig`

```
<article{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {{ created.content | date("d/m/Y") }}
  {{ content.title }}
  {{ content.body }}
</article>
```

The title is not displaying. How do I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use:

`{{ label }}` or `{{ node.label }}` or `{{ node.getTitle() }}`.